# Integrals and Fourier Transforms

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider the function $f(t),$ with:
$$
f(t)=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{y} e^{y^{2}} \cos (y t)\, dy
$$
Compute
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|f^{\prime}(t)\right|^{2}\, dt$$
where the prime denotes differentiation with respect to $t .$

To start off how would you differentiate $f(t)$ with respect to $t$ ? Is $y$ implicitly a function of $t$?

Comment: You have a $t$ in the factor $\cos(yt)$:
$$f'(t) = =\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{y} e^{y^{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \cos (y t)\, dy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate under the integral sign, meaning
$$ f'(t)=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{y} e^{y^{2}} {\partial \over \partial t}\cos (y t)\, dy $$
$$= -\int_{0}^{1} y\sqrt{y} e^{y^{2}} \sin (y t)\, dy $$
You want to be able to use Plancherel's Theorem here, so what you can do is write the integral as a symmetric sine transform as
$$-{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1} sgn(y)|y|^{3 \over 2} e^{y^{2}} \sin (y t)\, dy $$
$$=-{1 \over 2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[-1,1]}(y)sgn(y)|y|^{3 \over 2} e^{y^{2}} \sin (y t)\, dy $$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm assuming that $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ is just the inner integral. Why introduce an outer integral from positive infinity to negative infinity, and why are you permitted to?

Comment: the $\chi_{[-1,1]}(y)$ is the function that is one from $-1$ to $1$ and zero elsewhere. If we insert such a factor into the integral, then we can view the integral as an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and then use Plancherel's theorem to compute the integral you seek since we now have written the expression for $f'(t)$ as the sine transform of a function.

Comment: So we use the fact that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|f^{\prime}(t)\right|^{2}\, dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|F_{sin}(g(y))\right|^{2}\, dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|g(y)\right|^{2}\, dy$$ Wuth $F_{sin}(g(y))$ being the last line of your answer.

After computing everything I seem to get an answer of $0$, is that correct?